# setting struts property value to jsp session

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I want to set session as below but getting jsp exception

```
<input type="hidden" id="taxEngine" value="<s:property value="taxEngine"/>" />
```

hidden field is populating correctly but unable this to assign to session.

```
      <%
session.setAttribute("taxEngine", <s:property value="taxEngine"/>);
   %>
```

any suggesion how to set jsp element hidden value to scriptlet.

Comment: Why do you want to use scriptlet? It's a bad practice to use scriptlets in JSP.

Comment: right , I found other way around, thanks

Comment: @Surya Please answer your question

Comment: The scriptlet doesn't work for obvious reasons--scriptlets are already Java code and JSP tags have no meaning. But it makes no sense to assign something to the session in the view layer; set it in the code before you even hit the view.